# WindowsFormsHost not showing when Wpf Window style is set

Tags: wpf, styles, winforms-interop

I have a WPF Window that has a WinForms Button inside. When I set the Style of the Window the button isn't rendered, but when the Window Style is not set the Button appears as it should be.

Window Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Telbit.TeStudio.View.Forms.FloatingTestComponentsBrowser"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    Title="Test Components Browser" Style="{DynamicResource TSHUD}"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Closing="Window_Closing" >

    <Grid Name="windowContent" Height="300" Width="300">
            <WindowsFormsHost HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <wf:Button Text="Try" Name="btnTry" MaximumSize="100,25" BackColor="LightGray"/>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the Style for the window:

```
<Style x:Key="TSHUD" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0px"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    <Rectangle Fill="#ED111F29" Stroke="Black" Margin="29,29,29,29" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Effect="{DynamicResource TSWindowShadow}"/>

                    <Rectangle Name="TSHUDHeader" Stroke="Black" Margin="29,29,29,29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#ED1F3A45"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#EC111F29" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>

                    <Rectangle Name="TSHUDHeaderSplitter" Fill="#ED374551" Margin="30,54,30,29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="1"/>

                    <Label Name="TSHudTitle" Background="Transparent"
                               Margin="41,34,41,29" Padding="0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Title}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF8395B1" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </Label>

                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have other windows with the same style but only with WPF controls (some with default style and some with custom style) and there is no problem.

I've tried to [Enable Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750800.aspx) with no luck..

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: This is known limitation of `WindowsFormsHost`: when you set `AllowsTransparency="True"` your win-forms controls don't show up :( You can look at this here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6f9dd3b5-af92-4076-9b4e-1a770dd52f70/ but the workaround suggestion there is very ugly.

Comment: Oh damn it!
Anyway, if you answer as an answer I would mark your answuer as correct. I think I'm not able to do it in the comment

Comment: @repka: you help  me too! Please post it as an answer so that other people can see it